# Hide UIImageView from other UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

I have maybe stupid question but it is possible to set UIImageView hidden from other class?

I create property of it in one class and want to set it hide in other class. I try it but it is not working.

Here is what i am trying to do:

FirstClass.h:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
```

OtherClass.h:

```
@property FirstClass*firstClass;
```

OtherClass.m:

```
@synthesize fistClass;
```

and in my method:

```
[firstClass.image setHidden:YES];
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
[self.firstClass.image setHidden:YES];
```

If firstClass is a property in OtherClass, in an OtherClass method you need to reference the property on self. Also, as mentioned by YarGnawh, make sure your outlet is linked in the storyboard and that you are calling your code in or after awakeFromNib.

Comment: Still not working. Is it possible that my problem is that i have container view in same destination as my view with that image? That container view is my "second class" and VC which contain that container view and view with my image is my "first class". Can it make my troubles with that?

Comment: Here is a link to what am i talking about :) https://www.dropbox.com/s/gdsc18kjsznytf6/Sn%C3%ADmka%20obrazovky%202014-08-07%20o%C2%A013.56.14.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It's should work. Make sure you image view is linked up in your storyboard/xib